# RStudio create table with mutate and left_join functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm very new to R but I've had a lot of help so far on this forum thankfully! I have code that reads as follows:

```
socdem %>% 
  mutate(VISIT = as.character(VISIT)) %>%
  left_join(socdem,f06, by="WIHSID", copy = TRUE, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), na_matches)
```

I wanted to add:

```
table(socdem$RACE, IPV)
```

but when I add it on to the previous statement, RStudio locks up and won't give me an output (I think it's crashing because I can't save or stop the task the either).

Is it incorrect to try to create a table from the mutate and left_join commands? My issue is that I'm trying to create a table with RACE and IPV but the lengths of the variables don't match because they're coming from different datasets hence the mutate and left_join commands.

Comment: What do you mean by adding it? How are you adding it? If you want to see the results by RACE and IPV, try adding `%>% count(RACE, IPV)` after your `left_join()` call.

Comment: > # Race ~ IPV
> socdem %>% 
+   mutate(VISIT = as.character(VISIT)) %>%
+   left_join(f06, socdem, by="WIHSID", copy = TRUE, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), na_matches) %>%
+   count(socdem$RACE, IPV)
Error: Invalid index: out of bounds

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please provide a sample of your `socdem` dataset. You can use `dput(head(socdem))`

Comment: @jac911 you added `socdem$` in the `count()` function, which is not what I indicated. Also there shouldn't be `+`. Finally, what are you trying to achieve with `Race ~ IPV > socdem`?